# Writing Kotlin on openjdk 11+28, failing to import standard Java package

Tags: java, kotlin

My program is very simple, in a file called `app.kt`:

```
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.io.File

fun main(){
        println("Hello, world!")
// imported and used File API to show that importing java APIs generally seems to work
        println(File("./app.kt").readText())
// the below is necessary to ensure the above "import" isn't removed by the compiler
        var build = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
}
```

At runtime, I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/net/http/HttpRequest` on line 9, after compiling and running the code using the Kotlin command-line compiler.

The above runs without error when compiled and run via IntelliJ on Windows. I'm using WSL2, but have made sure that the versions of java/kotlin I'm using for compilation/runtime on WSL are installed under WSL, not Windows. If somebody could try on a real Ubuntu environment, I would be grateful.

`java --full-version` prints `openjdk 11+28`, and the best information I can find says that what I'm trying to import was added in JDK 11, so I shouldn't be having issues.

`kotlin -version` prints `Kotlin version 1.3.72-release-468 (JRE 11+28)`

I am compiling with the command `kotlinc *.kt -d app.jar -jvm-target 11` and running with the command `kotlin -classpath ./app.jar AppKt`

EDIT: Note, I do not have the same issue when compiling/running the following Java code:

```
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This will be efef");
        HttpRequest.Builder build = HttpRequest.newBuilder();
    }
}
```